# How to Rename Column name of table in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, ddl

I have the column name `ParentName` and for now i want to `rename` that column name to `Parent1FirstName`, so what is the query of that rename column name of my table

```
    ALTER TABLE tbltable1
    Rename ParentName = 'Parent1FirstName';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sp_rename` like following.

```
EXEC sp_rename 'tbltable1.ParentName ', 'Parent1FirstName', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'TableName.OldColumnName' , 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'
```